# Label formatting problems in Matlab pdf figures

Tags: matlab, plot, formatting

When I plot and save figures as pdf in Matlab, there are always formatting problems in the title, xlabel, and ylabel. This occurs when I use brackets, subscripts, superscripts, Greek letters, etc. The following code is an example:

```
kappa = 10;
tau = linspace(-1,1,100);
y = sin(kappa*tau);

figure('PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperSize', [4 3], 'PaperPosition', [0 0 4 3]);
plot(tau,y)
xlabel('time, \tau')
ylabel('amplitude \alpha')
title('amplitude, \alpha=sin(\kappa\tau)')

saveas(gcf,'myfig.pdf')
saveas(gcf,'myfig.jpg')
```

The pdf output looks like:

[image]

the labels have large spaces where there shouldn't be. This doesn't happen in jpg figures, or when I use LaTeX font for the labels.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to use [export_fig](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig)?

Comment: What OS and Matlab version are you using? Does [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1165657) help?